# C# What is the purpose of Func<object> getObject?

Tags: c#, func

I have found the following code snippet and was wondering what the purpose is of the `Func<object> getObject` property:

```
public void InsertCacheItem(string key, Func<object> getObject, TimeSpan duration)
{
    try
    {
        var value = getObject();
        if (value == null)
            return;

        key = GetCacheKey(key);

        _cache.Insert(
            key,
            value,
            null,
            System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration,
            duration,
            System.Web.Caching.CacheItemPriority.Normal,
            null);
    }
    catch { }
}
```

How do you call this particular function by passing the Func property?

Comment: why do they use this delegate instead of just passing the value of the object?

Comment: In the case of your code above, it's actually completely pointless.

Comment: @RandRandom oops, bad tag :) anyway the commenter deleted the cmment

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would call this with something like:

```
InsertCacheItem("bob", () => "valuetocache", TimeSpan.FromHours(1));
```

But why do it this way? Why not just pass in "valuetocache"? Well, mainly due to the `try..catch`. The code as written means that even if the `Func` fails to execute then the calling code isn't impacted.

So:

```
InsertCacheItem("bob", () => MethodThatThrowsException(), TimeSpan.FromHours(1));
```

will still work, for example. *It won't cache anything, but it won't bubble up exceptions to the calling code.*

Comment: Aah ok makes sense! Thanks for the intel

Comment: Just an aside, but if I found a function implemented this way in code review, I would be having a discussion with the developer that wrote it.  Even ignoring the "useless" delegate, the empty and undocumented `catch` is a code smell.

Comment: The code smell is the missing documentation. That's also the reason why OP asked this question. But the code itself makes sense as this answer shows. `MethodThatThrowsException` might be in another (3rd party) library or a delegate that is injected. However, it must be ensured that this code runs without exception.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of your code above, it's actually almost pointless other than to catch the exception. You would more usually see this in a function to retrieve something from a cache. For example:

```
public object GetCacheItem(string key, Func<object> getObject, TimeSpan duration)
{
    var value = GetItemFromCache(key);

    if (value == null)
    {
        value = getObject();

        _cache.Insert(
            key,
            value,
            null,
            System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration,
            duration,
            System.Web.Caching.CacheItemPriority.Normal,
            null);
    }

    return value;
}
```

Now we retrieve from the cache if we can, otherwise we call the potentially expensive operation to create the value again. For example:

```
var listOfZombies = GetCacheItem(
    "zombies", 
    () => GetZombiesFromDatabaseWhichWillTakeALongTime(), 
    TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10));
```

Comment: i still don't understand, if just to catch some exception, then if just pass an **object instead of a Func** will have the same effect(since a simple value will not cause exception), so why use `Func`?

Comment: Exactly, that's why I said it's virtually useless.

Comment: How did you get the `simple value` @LeiYang? Does the code to get the `simple value` have **any chance** of throwing an exception? Since, if it does, that is what this use of `Func` is trying to solve.

Comment: @mjwills what if i get the value outside of the function which is also wrapped with a try catch and then pass the value in? when there's no `Func` say in .net 1.1, do you mean we cannot catch exceptions?

Comment: @LeiYang Yes, that would definitely work. The advantage of the approach shown in the original post is that if you have 100 callers to `InsertCacheItem` you need only a single try..catch rather than 100 of them.